# Xperia Play MTP driver fails to install

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-play, mtp

When trying to update my Xperia Play with PC Companion, it fails to install the drivers for my device. I plug it in, it tries up until it says a problem has occured installing the hardware. My screen looks like:

[because stackexchange doesn't let me post images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7q6Z.png)

I've tried it's recommended diagnostic advice, null.

edit: Just installed the update on another computer. It seems to work fine. If you don't have a spare, try a VM.

Comment: Remove the usb drivers and try rebooting the machine again?